# Adding different files on different hadoop nodes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

When we add files with

> bin/hadoop dfs -put input_folder input

by this command in HDFS.
When we add files , they are replicated to all the nodes.

Is there any way by which we can distribute different files on different nodes , means suppose i have 4 file A,B,C,D.I will add file A and B on node 1 and remaining on node 2.
Is this scenario possible?

If yes then what happens in case of node failure?

Comment: Any reasons for for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have not changed your replication factor. The default is 3 which means you have three replica from each file. if you have 2 data nodes all files will be replicated to all data nodes. decrease this value until it fits your needs.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```

If nodes fails and no other replicas exists, You can not access those files

Comment: I have already set it 2.Because i have a master and slave where my master also acts as a slave.My question was can i replicate file A and B on node1 and just file B and C on node2? And then sum up there result.

Comment: @CodeBanger: No You can't. `FSDataOutputStream` which is responsible for writing data, contacts name node to save files. There is no such option in this class.

Comment: thnx dude. and using what will be beneficial for me apache hadoop , or cloudera hadoop? And why?

Comment: @CodeBanger: It depends. for purpose of learning and discovering it doesn't matter. But if you are going to manage a cluster, 100% you should consider cloudera. Cloudera manager(free or enterprise edition) is truly awesome.

Comment: Again thank you , but i have read somewhere that you can combine scribe and hadoop and i guess scribe logs different files on different nodes.
So do it handles then?

Comment: @CodeBanger: Of course you can write different files on different nodes but you need bunch of data nodes (more than replication factor) so that name node can distribute files on them. scribe uses libhdfs to connect hadoop cluster which is same as connecting with `FSDataOutputStream`. see this link (To conclude part) to see the scribe architecture: http://blog.octo.com/en/scribe-a-way-to-aggregate-data-and-why-not-to-directly-fill-the-hdfs/

Comment: Hello again @Majid Azimi,

i read the article , there was nothing about different data on different nodes.I am still not understanding if i enable scribe for logging then will it add same data on all nodes?
Or i am very confused between your previous comment 'bunch of datanodes' and 'replication factor'. Because what i have experimented till now hadoop replicates same data on all nodes..
Can you please explain me?

Comment: @CodeBanger You have configured replication factor to 2: means each file will have two replicas. Then you have only two nodes. So what is the result? Any file you add will be on all nodes. suppose you have 10 nodes and replication factor is 2, then: file1 will be on for example node1, node2. file2 will be on node 7, node 8. and so on... load balancing across these nodes is done by name node. There is nothing manual about that. all done automatically by name node.